# Problem building a Dropdown with plotly-Dash in python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

[the code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH1BZ.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eutjq.png)

the error indicates that the elements inside options must be objects, but apparently they are not being recognized.
I'm new to programming, but I've looked for answers elsewhere and haven't found them. I preferred to be more direct and try to resolve my problem.

If anyone can help me I would be grateful, as this problem is interfering with my studies. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is easier for us if you copy the code itself instead of a screenshot.  Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just incorrectly capitalizing the word "Label", instead of "label".  Just copy the example here:

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output,callback

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'New York City'},
            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'Montreal'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'San Francisco'},
        ],
        value='Montreal'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Glad to help!  @FilipeGianino go ahead and accept the answer to mark the question as answered.